# Put subreport with paging in footer

Tags: reporting-services, pagination, ssrs-2008, bids

We have about 100 different reports. All of them have the same footer, which contains a Page Number, and maybe some other text. The footer design may change regularly.

So now, for exmaple, if we want to change the footer from "Page 1 of 5" to "P. 1/5", **this has to be done for each report**, i.e. 100 times.

I would like to be able to put a Subreport in the footer instead, and then only one change will be needed. However, SSRS won't let you insert a Subreport in the footer (CrystalReports let's you do that).

What can be done?

Comment: check this link out for re using the footer in all the SSRS reports http://www.ascendra.com/?q=blog/ssrs-reusable-headers-and-footers

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SQL Server 2008 R2 and Report Builder, you could create your footer details inside a rectangle and publish that rectangle as a Report Part. You would then just need to open reports in Report Builder and run a "Check for Updates" to update the footer.